# Accessing a function within a function from outside in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested function that I want to call from outside.

```
var _Config = "";
var tourvar;
function runtour() {
    if (_Config.length != 0) {
        tourvar = $(function () {
            var config = _Config,
                autoplay = false,
                showtime,
                step = 0,
                total_steps = config.length;
            showControls();
            $('#activatetour').live('click', startTour);
            function startTour() {
            }
            function showTooltip() {
            }
        });
    }
}
function proceed() {
    tourvar.showTooltip();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    runtour();
});
```

I was hoping to call it by tourvar.showTooltip(); but I seem to be wrong :)  How can I make showTooltip() available from outside the function?

Comment: What is the `$` for? is it because you make use of jQuery or some other library? in that case, which library is it?

Comment: Just declare the function outside. There are no reasons to declare it inside other function.

Comment: `tourvar.showTooltip = function(){ ... }` (although you're going to have to work with native JS objects, not jQuery wrapped ones).

Comment: FYI: `$(function(){})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){});`.  So, when you do `tourvar = $(function(){`, you are setting `tourvar` to `$(document)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since my previous answer was really a hot headed one, I decided to delete it and provide you with another one:

```
var _Config = "";
var tourvar;

// Module pattern
(function() {
    // private variables
    var _config, autoplay, showtime, step, total_steps; 

    var startTour = function() { };

    var showTooltip = function() { };

    // Tour object constructor
    function Tour(config) {
        _config = config;
        autoplay = false;
        step = 0;
        total_steps = _config.length;

        // Provide the user with the object methods
        this.startTour = startTour;
        this.showTooltip = showTooltip;
    }

    // now you create your tour
if (_Config.length != 0) {
        tourvar = new Tour(_Config);
    }
})();

function proceed() {
    tourvar.showTooltip();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    runtour();    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response....  I have made a slight change but get a Tour undefined.  I moved if (_Config.length != 0) {
        tourvar = new Tour(_Config);
        tourvar.showControls();
    } into the function runtour which should kick the tour off and the showcontrols function should show the control. I declared the ShowControls var in function Tour(). Anway, when I runtour() I get Tour is undefined.

Comment: sorted it... 99% your code... the only other thing was because I had redacted some... thanks for your help... understand this alot more now.

Comment: Glad it helped. Just for others to clarify, the problem was that the Tour() constructor was not visible outside the module. I modified the example and now it should be as easy to use as possible, be sure to take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/pm9Kb/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
function outerFunction() {
    window.mynestedfunction = function() {
    }
}
mynestedfunction();
```